# How to receive all the prefetch rabbitmq messages using spring framework?

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-jms

I am learning to how use SimpleMessageListenerContainer to receive rabbitmq messages. My listener container has prefetchCount = 1000. However my listener worker implements the MessageListener interface which only   receive one message at a time. Is there an interface to receive a list of messages? If there is not, how can I do to receive a list of messages? I don't want to process one message at a time but rather a list of them so I can do batch insert/update. I also want to acknowledge once for all of the messages that were delivered to me.

Thanks,

Sean Nguyen

Answer (score 0):

There is no such API; even the low-level rabbit client consumer delivers each prefetched message one at a time (via `handleDelivery`).

You will have to accumulate them into a list yourself.

Use the `txSize` property (set it the same as prefetch) to send a single ack after 1000 deliveries.

Comment: Is there a way to know the nth message that I am received so if nth == 1000, i can acknowledge it?

Comment: If you use `txSize=1000` the container will ack after 1000; if you want to ack yourself, use a `ChannelAwareMessageListener`, set the acknowledge mode to `MANUAL` (instead of the default `AUTO`) and issue a `basicAck` on the Channel (use the deliveryTag from `message.gertMessageProperties().getDeliveryTag()`).

Comment: @Gary: I have similar situation. I know it is unconventional use but my listener calls third party service which performs better if I pass string joining N (say 10) message (json) bodies. You suggested using txSize and accumulate in list. But I am not sure how to do that. I can use auto container ack. What listener I should use? I am using     "@Bean
    public MessageListener messageListener() {
        return new MessageListener() {
            public void onMessage(Message message) { ....}"

Comment: Siimply accumulate the messages into a thread-safe collection within your message listener then when you reach the number you want, send them all off to the next stage. When the stage completes, the ack will be sent (as long as your txSize matches your collection size).

Comment: @GaryRussell what if it's the last "batch" when the the batch don't have enought messages, for example prefetchCount = 10 but queue just has only 7 messages left

Comment: Don't ask new questions on old answers; especially when they are 7+ years old. The framework has evolved since then; it now has the concept of a batch listener, using the `batchSize` and `receiveTImeout` - a short batch is delivered if no records are received within the timeout. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#de-batching and https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#receiving-batch