# Using container transcated and txsize

Tags: spring-amqp

I have similar requirement as post: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27896778/how-to-receive-all-the-prefetch-rabbitmq-messages-using-spring-framework)

(I added comment there and got response but posting as new question to post code)

Basically I have a need to combine 10 messages in a queue listener and then call third party service passing the combined message (message body is json, so basically I need to join 10 json strings into one). It is unconventional use of messaging for sure but this is the best place in my flow if I can do it.

I have following code but it is still not working. I have published 3 messages on the queue and all three are acked individually. Obviously my understanding is wrong. What I thought was since listener received only 3 messages (less than txsize 10), it will not ack any messages until it receives 10 messages.

```
        @Bean
SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    ..
    ..
     container.setChannelTransacted(true);
    container.setPrefetchCount(10);
    container.setTxSize(10);
    return container;
}


private int txcount = 1;
List<String> syncList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());

@Bean
public MessageListener messageListener() {
    return new MessageListener() {
        public void onMessage(Message message) {
            ObjectMapper mapper = ConfiguredObjectMapper.getObjectMapper();
            String json = new String(message.getBody(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            syncList.add(json);
            txcount++;
            System.out.println("###############txcount is: " + txcount);
            if (txcount == 1000){ //call remote serivice - join list and pass as parameter}
        }
    }
}
```

#

EDIT 1
I tried amqp client consumer from other post and it seems to be work fine.But I still would like to try with listener with txSize and compare performance & failure scenarios.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
    connectionFactory.setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(true);

    connectionFactory.setHost("localhost");
    connectionFactory.setPort(5672);
    connectionFactory.setUsername("rabbituser");
    connectionFactory.setPassword("rabbitpwd");
    connectionFactory.setVirtualHost("svi_vhost");
    boolean autoReconnect = true;
    int reconnectInterval = 5000;
    int prefetch = 10;
    List<String> messages = null;
    Long lastDeliveryTag = null;

    while (true) {
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = connectionFactory.newConnection();
            Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
            channel.basicQos(prefetch);

            QueueingConsumer consumer = new QueueingConsumer(channel);
            boolean autoAck = false;
            channel.basicConsume("my.queue", false, consumer);

            while (true) {
                try {
                    QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = consumer.nextDelivery(500);
                    if (delivery == null) {
                        if (messages != null && messages.size() > 0) {
                            callRemoteService(String.join("\n", messages));
                            messages = null;
                            channel.basicAck(lastDeliveryTag, true);
                        }
                    }else {
                        if (messages == null) messages = new ArrayList<String>(prefetch);
                        String json = new String(delivery.getBody(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                        lastDeliveryTag = delivery.getEnvelope().getDeliveryTag();
                        messages.add(json);
                        if (messages.size() == prefetch) {
                            callRemoteService(String.join("\n", messages));
                            messages = null;
                            channel.basicAck(lastDeliveryTag, true);
                        }
                    }
                }catch(Exception ex){
                    LOGGER.info(ex.getMessage(), ex);
                    throw new AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException("Error Processing message:"+messages.toString());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.warn(e.getMessage());
        }

        if (autoReconnect) {
            try {
                releaseConn(connection);
                if (connection != null) connection.close();
                LOGGER.info("[*] Will try to reconnect to remote host in " + reconnectInterval / 1000 + " seconds.");
                Thread.sleep(reconnectInterval);
            }catch (InterruptedException ie) {

            }
        }
        else
            break;
    }
}
```

#

EDIT 2

@Artem, I am trying to write a listener which should collect N messages (if the q has N or more messages) and then join message bodies to form json string and then call a remote micro service passing the joined string as parameter. The remote service can take joined json from 1 to N messages but performance will be far better if we send json from N (10+) messages. So basically I want to prefetch N messages, then loop through each message, append message body to a json string and then call remote service. I have written a ampq client consumer with basicConsume (listed as UPDATE 1 above) and it seems to work fine but I wanted to see if there is a way to use one of the available spring listener for better exception/connection error/restart scenarios. In another post it is mentioned that using transactions/txSize, I can loop through messages and auto ack will be send after txSize loop.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, looks like you misunderstood it a bit.

Let me share with the code how it looks:

```
private boolean doReceiveAndExecute(BlockingQueueConsumer consumer) throws Throwable {

    Channel channel = consumer.getChannel();

    for (int i = 0; i < txSize; i++) {

        logger.trace("Waiting for message from consumer.");
        Message message = consumer.nextMessage(receiveTimeout);
        if (message == null) {
            break;
        }
        try {
            executeListener(channel, message);
        }
        catch (ImmediateAcknowledgeAmqpException e) {
            break;
        }
        catch (Throwable ex) {//NOSONAR
            consumer.rollbackOnExceptionIfNecessary(ex);
            throw ex;
        }

    }

    return consumer.commitIfNecessary(isChannelLocallyTransacted(channel));

}
```

As you see the framework has there a loop by the `txSize` and in the finish of the loop it does the `ack` for fetched messages.

If consumer doesn't return message, there is a `break` which ends up with the `ack` exactly for that count of messages which could be fetched during this cycle.

Just after that the `ListenerContainer` starts the new iteration with the same logic.

So, your `txcount++;` logic is really wrong.

As Gary answered the to you, there is no such a built-in feature.

Seems for me you should take a look to the [Spring Integration](http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/) and its `Aggregator` implementation.

Comment: Just to be clear, the container will ack after `txSize` __attempts__ to receive a message, based on the receive timeout; this means 10 messages or 10 seconds with the default timeout. You can increase the timeout but that will make the container less responsive to a `stop()` request. You could also consider using manual acks, in which case you need a `SessionAwareMessageListener` and issue `basicAck` when you want.

Comment: @Gary, I could not make the listener work. Could you please please post sample code with listener signature and tzSize usage. In the mean while I tried amqp client consumer (as posted in update above) and it seems to work fine.

Comment: I am not available for the next two weeks. If you still need help then, ping me again.

Comment: @Artem, Could you please post sample code with listener signature and tzSize usage. I read some docs about Spring Integration and I think it may be  a bit heavy for my use case. Pinged Gary but he is out. Really appreciate your time.

Comment: Well. Let's start from the beginning! What is your requirement? It isn't clear to me what I should do for you... Please, share more your mind to allow me to make a proper surgery :-)

Comment: @Artem :-), Added my requirement as UPDATE 2 in the question.

Comment: @Artem, could you please please post code snippet using txSize with  my SimpleMessageListenerContainer? I am totally lost now. Thanks.